# python tkinter - how do I see specific value in the input field

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my code

So when I run the script I want my input field to show the value in list_val i.e 23 in this case. How do I do that?
At the moment nothing shows up in my input field.
Also, if I replace the input field with some other number it should replace the value in list_val.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list_val = [23]
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

def myClick():
    myLabel =  Label(root,text= e.get())
    myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text='Enter Value', command = myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your problem? You don't know how to update the content of an `Entry` widget?

Comment: As explained in the main body- when I run the script input field should show me the current value in the list (list_val). Also any value you type in the input field to overwrite the current data (i.e. 23 in this case) should get updated in list_val. So the new value should replace 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things: you create a new Label each time the function `myClick()` runs. Instead create the label in the main program and let `myClick()` update the Label contents.

Then let the `myClick()` function also update the `list_val` contents.

Have a look at this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list_val = [23]
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()
e.insert(0, list_val[0])    # Insert value from list_val in Entry

def myClick():
    myLabel.config(text=e.get())    # Set Label to Entry contents
    list_val[0] = e.get()           # Update list_val with Entry contents

myButton = Button(root, text='Enter Value', command = myClick)
myButton.pack()

myLabel = Label(root)   # Create label first w/o any text
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Is this what you are after?